# How to specify edges with arguments in mutation's fat query

Tags: relayjs

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613879/should-the-opaque-cursors-in-connections-be-stable-across-different-field-args/32615799#32615799) it should be possible to specify edges with arguments in fat query, but I can't make it work. Here are is my mutation config and fat query:

```
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on AddCommentPayload {
      commentEdge(sort:[{createdAt: ASC}])
      customer {
        id
        comments
      }
    }
  `;
}

getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'RANGE_ADD',
    parentName: 'customer',
    parentID: this.props.customer.id,
    connectionName: 'comments',
    edgeName: 'commentEdge',
    rangeBehaviors() {
      return 'append';
    },
  }];
}
```

Problem is that resulting query doesn't contain any arguments on edge field:

```
mutation AddComment($input_0:AddCommentInput!) {
  addComment(input:$input_0) {
    clientMutationId,
    ...F1
  }
}
fragment F0 on Customer {
  id
}
fragment F1 on AddCommentPayload {
  commentEdge {
    cursor,
    __typename,
    node {
      id,
      createdAt,
      commentText
    }
  },
  customer {
    id,
    ...F0
  }
}
```